# Ask the user to input a decimal number, displays how many digits come before the decimal point and how many comes after it in c#

Tags: c#, numbers, decimal

I have a decimal variable type and want to check the number of digits both before and after the decimal point.

I've rounded numbers and counted the number of digits in an integer but I am unsure how to tackle this, what should I do? For example, 345.65 should return** 3 digits before decimal point, 2 digits after decimal point**.

Comment: Turn value into `string` with a help of `.ToString()` and find decimal searator with a help of `IndexOf`

Comment: Attempted this but got the error 'double does not contain a definition for Indexof ', despite using .ToString() .

Comment: `double` doesn't habe `IndexOf`, but `string` does. Please, see my answer

Comment: The question mentions "decimal variable type". Are you actually using the `Decimal` type or just regular floating point `double`?

Answer (score 0):

Turn `value` into `string`, find position of the decimal separator (`.IndexOf`) and compute:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

var value = 345.65;

string text = Math.Abs(value).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int position = text.IndexOf('.');

int before = position >= 0 ? position : text.Length;
int after = position >= 0 ? text.Length - position - 1 : 0;

// Let's have a look        
Console.WriteLine($"{value}, before: {before}, after: {after}");
```

Output:

```
345.65, before: 3, after: 2
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PI4nJt)